# Storing unique characters in Python

Tags: php, python, mysql, facebook

While logging in with the Facebook on my site all the likes of the new user are stored in the DB. But while storing the unique characters (characters from the other languages and all) are not getting stored and I get a error like this:

```
Warning at /facebook/connect/

**Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x99\xA5 Lo...' for column 'name' at row 1**

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://pydev.aviesta.com/facebook/connect/?facebook_login=1
Django Version:     1.4.2
Exception Type:     Warning
Exception Value:    

Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x99\xA5 Lo...' for column 'name' at row 1

Exception Location:     /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _warning_check, line 89
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/mnt/aviesta/pythondev/mezzanine_aviesta',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/satchless-2011.9.pre-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_mptt-0.5.4-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_sorting-0.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_memcached-1.48-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.12-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_treebeard-1.61-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_haystack-2.0.0_beta-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_extra_views-0.2.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/mnt/software/django-oscar',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_extensions-0.9.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_facebook-4.0.8-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_socialregistration-0.5.8-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mock-1.0.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info',
 '/mnt/aviesta/pythondev/mezzanine_aviesta/webdev']
```

Comment: I think you need to add some escape sequence in your query , ANy way its better if you post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-ascii characters, it's better to use utf-8 as the default charset. So you should make sure that your database or table is encoding string with utf-8. And if you are working with Django, it already handles utf-8 stuff be default. The only thing you should care is the output from third-party service's response, which may not be encoded in utf-8.

Comment: I have already applied these things for my DB. But still its giving the same error . Not sure what is actually happening there.!

Comment: @RanbirSingh I try to print the '\xE2\x99\xA5' in Pythons shell, it gives a ♥ character, I'm not sure if this is the correct character. And it's valid to assign to a Django models.CharField. So maybe you can put more related code here.

Comment: Yes I think so this one is the character that is not getting saved .

Comment: Can you assign it to the name filed in Django shell and save without error?